# React-Joyride 'Target not visible' message when stopping mid-tutorial

Tags: reactjs

I'm using react-joyride for a user-tutorial.
One of the targets is a menu-entry in a dropdown menu which is closed initially (so target is not visible).
In the joyride callback, I detect when it's time to show the dropdown and manipulate the css to make the element visible. It all works fine if I click Next until the end.

If, however, I close the tutorial in the middle, right before that step, I get a warning 'Target not visible'. This is because it already loads the next step (even though I fire the 'stop' action).

Is there a way to avoid this? Or is it intentional that you can only focus on elements that are at all times visible on the page?

Thanks for any input.